# Retrieving images from list

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have to store images and toggle the images based on response.
For example:

```
int[] fimg = new int[]{
    R.drawable.apple,
    R.drawable.banana,
    R.drawable.org,
    R.drawable.pgranate,
    R.drawable.melon,
    R.drawable.grapes
};
```

I used this method to store, but how to retrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using List here but Array,
In order to use a list do

```
List<integer> list = new ArrayList<integer>()
  for( String f : fimg ) {
  list.add(f);
}
```

Now you you can simply retrieve by

```
list.get(position)

(ImageView image = (Imageview) new findViewById(list.get(position));)
```

It will return the `int` !

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
myImageView.setImageResource(fimg[0]); //0 is the index of your int array
```